# What is the exact algorithm spring-date-neo4j follows when saving relationships in simple mapping and how can I control it?

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have an issue with one of my projects. I am using **spring-data-neo4j 3.1.4** without aspects (**simple mapping** only).

My graph structure is a **calendar tree** where each level (Year, Month, Day) has link to parent, link to next and previous and links to first and last children. This all is modelled using different relationship names for each level (NEXT_YEAR, NEXT_MONTH, ...). Similar to http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html, but I have the NEXT links at each level.

**Links** to next and previous use the **same relationship** type, but the **opposite direction**.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Month extends CalendarTreeEntity {
    @Indexed(numeric = true)
    Integer month;

    @RelatedTo(type = "CONTAINS_MONTH", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    @Fetch
    Year year;

    @RelatedTo(type = "FIRST_DAY", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    Day firstDay;

    @RelatedTo(type = "LAST_DAY", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    Day lastDay;

    @RelatedTo(type = "NEXT_MONTH", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    Month nextMonth;

    @RelatedTo(type = "NEXT_MONTH", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    Month previousMonth;
}
```

This is the example of one of my entities. I can see in the debugger that all fetched entitites in the currently loaded tree use the same instances for the same nodes (I implemented a cache as workaround to https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-514). The relationship entities that have not been fetched contain all NULLs except the nodeId.

All works properly including insertions and traversal while inside a single transaction. I have the insertion covered by tests and all links are maintained properly on all levels. When a link is changed I update both sides.

One important thing to mention is that I can't save the inserted nodes immediately, because I am sometimes inserting temporary nodes in read-only transactions and use them for traversal. So the save happens only when the whole calendar tree is updated.

Once I try to fetch the tree in another transaction (new request) and insert a Day (for example), it breaks with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot obtain single field value for field 'nextMonth' during neo4jTemplate.save(day). (There can also be a new Month  or Year entity referenced from the Day).

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot obtain single field value for field 'nextMonth'
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToSingleFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToSingleFieldAccessor.getValue(RelatedToSingleFieldAccessorFactory.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.getValue(DefaultEntityState.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyEntityStatePropertyValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$000(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$2.doWithAssociation(SourceStateTransmitter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:324)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesFrom(SourceStateTransmitter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.loadEntity(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:112)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.createEntityFromState(Neo4jTemplate.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelationshipHelper.createEntitySetFromRelationshipEndNodes(RelationshipHelper.java:150)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToFieldAccessor.createEntitySetFromRelationshipEndNodesUsingTypeProperty(RelatedToFieldAccessor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToSingleFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToSingleFieldAccessor.getValue(RelatedToSingleFieldAccessorFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.getValue(DefaultEntityState.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyEntityStatePropertyValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$000(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$2.doWithAssociation(SourceStateTransmitter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:324)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesFrom(SourceStateTransmitter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.loadEntity(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:112)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:244)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:356)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:350)
    at cz.lkbrno05.repositories.CalendarTreeRepositoryImpl.saveTree(CalendarTreeRepositoryImpl.java:231)
```

**So my question is:**

- How exactly does the simple mapping save work?
- How does it traverse the unsaved entities (unmanaged, no nodeId)?
- What does it do to relationship updates on managed entities?

Also a small side question:
 - How does it deal with updates to entities on both sides of a relationship when both entities have the RelateTo field?

As you can see my relationship here is 1:1, but somehow SDN manages to add more than one edge. Or is it not able to update the relationship by deleting the old edge and creating a new one? Or is it possibly related to the fact that it traverses the nodes and finds references to the same nodeId multiple times (but in unfetched state)? I can't really avoid that unless the session cache is properly implemented as referenced in the [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-514).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some inconsistency in your object model

If I understand your model correctly then this should hold:

```
this == this.previousMonth.nextMonth
this == this.nextMonth.previousMonth
```

Here is a simple reproducing test case:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Month {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @RelatedTo(type = "MY_REL", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    Month next;

    @RelatedTo(type = "MY_REL", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    Month previous;
```

Test code:

```
    Month m1 = new Month("m1");
    Month m2 = new Month("m2");

    Month mX = new Month("mX");

    // this is correct
    m1.setNext(mX);
    mX.setPrevious(m1);

    // this messes up the model
    m2.setNext(mX);

    monthRepository.save(m1);
    monthRepository.save(mX);
    monthRepository.save(m2);

    Result<Month> result = monthRepository.findAll();

    List<Month> all = result.as(List.class);
```

Comment: Yes it does. But I am always setting both directions and fixing up the neighbors. Just like in double linked list. I have no problem with consistency until I try to save and load from the database. That is why I asked for explanation of the internals of save process.